# ubuntu 22.04LTS with nvidia rtx 3060 not working( (NVidia Geforce RTX 3060, Ubuntu 22.04, Asus Tuf)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 22.04

I have new Aus Tuf dash 15 with win11 preinstalled. I created dual boot with Ubuntu ubuntu 22.04LTS, but I cannot make nvidia card working. If I install the drivers via the "Additional Drivers" section of "Software & Updates":

> "NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage from nvidia-driver-525-open (proprietary, tested)"

the computer either stops to boot or the screen freezes after a while and HDMI is not working. I have tried several different approaches now and finally reinstalled the system to start from scratch, because I am truly lost. Lately I have followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446979), but the effect was as described previously.

- My computer has an Intel processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12650H × 16.
- The installed Linux kernel is 5.15.0-57-generic.
- Secure boot is disabled now.

Please help me, I don't want to stuck with windows.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Did you use the `autoinstall` option of the `ubuntu-drivers` terminal program to automatically select the recommended Nvidia proprietary graphics driver for your graphics card or did you just guess which driver to install?

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Pilot6 Please see mine https://shrib.com/#asustufdash12121 My kernel is 5.19.0-40-generic but rest all are same

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing [liquorix](https://liquorix.net/) kernel.

Answer (score -1):

Use "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)"
instead.

Comment: As written this is not a good answer. Why and how are needed to be added.